# Find longest repeating substring with length between x and y

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Given a string : "blablafblafbla" and 2 limits : x=3, y=5
I want to find the longest repeating substring that has the length between x and y.If there are many, the first one
In my example that would be "blaf"
Several questions:
1. is it easier to use regex?
2.I know how to find the longest substring but where do i have to put the conditions for it to be between x and y?

```
public static String longestDuplicate(String text)
{
    String longest = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 2 * longest.length() * 2; i++)
    {
        OUTER: for (int j = longest.length() + 1; j * 2 < text.length() - i; j++)
        {
            String find = text.substring(i, i + j);
            for (int k = i + j; k <= text.length() - j; k++)
            {
                if (text.substring(k, k + j).equals(find))
                {
                    longest = find;
                    continue OUTER;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your control statements are _bad_. I strongly suggest that you learn better practices when writing code. why are you using labels? Is there really need for a 'continue' statement there or could the loop have been designed differently?

Comment: what does it mean "bad"?

Comment: @LuciC: There are multiple problems with this code. Almost any time you have to use directed `break` or `continue`, you want to step back and say "Hmmm, maybe I've got myself in some trouble here." *Especially* if you find yourself writing a loop that will never actually loop unless an inner loop throws a directed `continue` at it, as with your loop labelled `OUTER`. Having significant calculations in the terminal condition of a loop is another danger signal. But this is all stuff for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not SO. :-)

Comment: @LuciC: FWIW, that code doesn't work. It finds `"bla"` rather than `"blaf"` for the given input. http://pastie.org/6094127

Comment: you're right... i have corrected now.

Comment: repeating continuously or just repeated once?

Comment: In your example, the longest repeated substring is `blafblaf`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provide is  an extremely inefficient way to solve the problem you have. I would implement the solution using [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) or some other rolling hash algorithm and this will enable you to solve your problem with complexity `O((y-x) * L)`.

You can't use regular expressions here- they are meant to solve copletely different tasks.

As for your question on how to use **your solution** to find longest substring with length between `x` and `y`, simply modify the loop over `j` to only consider values that are in the interval `[x, y]`. Here is how you can do that.

```
for (int j = Math.max(longest.length() + 1, x) ; j * 2 < text.length() - i && j < y; j++)
```

EDIT: to find the longest substring, reverse the for cycle:

```
for (int j = Math.min((text.length() - i -1)/2, y) ; j > longest.length() && j >=x; j--)
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why do you think so? I answer the qustion on how to solve the problem efficiently- using Rabin-Karp. I also add a few notes which **can** be comments but fit here too.

Comment: i know it's inefficient but this would be further integrated into some socket algorithm, jms, rmi, jsp and i need to use only basic things

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just as you wrote this I added a last sentence on applying the limits in the current solution.

Comment: @LuciC: In general, you'll have much more luck integrating clean code. When you have a loop that never loops unless an inner loop throws a `continue` at it, you know you have a problem with your code. :-)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: There you go. :-)

Comment: could you suggest an example of how could i rearrange the code?

Comment: @LuciC I have added the changed loop, take another look,

Comment: the result it's not the correct one. for the example string "blablafblafbla" it gives me "bla", but it should be "blaf"

Comment: @LuciC no according to your statement it is `bla` - this is the first repeating substring with length in the given range.

Comment: yes, that's right, but my problems was finding the longest one... maybe i wasn't clear enough....i'm Romanian...

Comment: Ahh then do the loop in the opposite direction. Instead of incrementing j decrement it. Also change it initial value.

Comment: @LuciC sorry a little mistake. I think correct answer is `blaf` and the problem is that you have to change the for cycle to: `for (int j = Math.min((text.length() - i -1)/2, y) ; j > longest.length() && j >=x; j--)` Notice I have removed the equality for `j >= longest.length()`.

Comment: still not getting "blaf", only "lafb"...with other string  ("blablafblafblafblaf") i get the correct "blafb"

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int commonPrefix (String string, int x, int y)
{
    int l = string.length ();
    int n = 0;
    int oy = y;
    while (x < oy && y < l && string.charAt (x) == string.charAt (y))
    {
        n++; x++; y++;
    }
    return n;
}

public static String longestRepeatingSubstring (
    String string, int minLength, int maxLength)
{
    String found = null; 

    int l = string.length ();
    int fl = minLength; 
    for (int x = 0; x < l - fl * 2; x++)
        for (int y = x + 1; y < l - fl; y++)
        {
            int n = commonPrefix(string, x, y);

            if (n >= maxLength)
                return string.substring(x, x + maxLength);

            if (n > fl)
            {
                found = string.substring (x, x + n);
                fl = n;
            }
        }

    return found;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println (longestRepeatingSubstring ("blablafblafblafblaf", 3, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clunky implementation with regex:

```
//import java.util.regex.*;

public static String longestRepeatingSubstring (String string, int min, int max)
{
  for (int i=max; i>=min; i--){
    for (int j=0; j<string.length()-i+1; j++){

      String substr = string.substring(j,j+i);
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(substr);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

      int count = 0;
      while (matcher.find()) count++;

      if (count > 1) return substr;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println (longestRepeatingSubstring ("blablafblafbla", 3, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int getCount(String string , String subString){

    int count = 0;
    int fromIndex = 0;
    do{
    if(string.indexOf(subString, fromIndex) != -1){
        count++;
        fromIndex = string.indexOf(subString, fromIndex);
    }
    }while(fromIndex == string.length()-1);
    return count;
}
public static String longestRepeatingSubstring (int min,int max , String string){
    Vector substrs = new Vector();
    Vector substrs_length = new Vector();
    for (int i=min; i<=max; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<string.length()-i+1; j++){
            String substr=string.substring(j, i+j);
            System.out.println(substr);
            if (substrs.indexOf(substr) == -1){
                int count =getCount(string, substr);
                if (count != 0) {
                    substrs.addElement(substr);
                    substrs_length.addElement(count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int maxLength = 0;
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ;  i < substrs_length.size() ; i++){
        int length = (int) substrs_length.elementAt(i);
        if(length > maxLength){
            maxLength = length;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return (String) substrs.elementAt(index);
}
public static void main(String [] arg){
    System.out.print(longestRepeatingSubstring(3, 5, "blablafblafbla"));
}
```